# Can the colour of a cell be changed once it has been selected?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I am doing a large amount of data entry but down a list which is already populated i.e. I am changing slightly the entries if they meet certain requirements.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to get a cell to change colour once it has been selected?

The work flow I want is:

Select cell at the top --> make alteration if necessary --> press enter to go down to next cell --> the cell changes from red to green.

The idea is that when I take a break or check different values in the same excel sheet I can very easily find where I left off without having write down the row number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much easier to change colour of the cell when you select it (rather than after deselecting).  To do this:
Right-click the sheet tab
Click 'view code'
Paste the following into the window that pops up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
End Sub
```

Try it.

Comment: That is very helpful, is there a way to restrict it into just column E?

Comment: @AlexMartin.  Yes, add this to the front of the second line: `if target.column = 5 then`